# Prove that the lebesgue integrals $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[0,1]^n} \frac{x_1^2+ \dots +x_n^2}{x_1+ \dots +x_n} \ d \mathrm{m}(\mathbf{x})=2/3$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I found this problem while studying for an analysis exam and have been puzzled ever since. If anybody has any hints on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Prove that the lebesgue integrals $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[0,1]^n} \frac{x_1^2+ \dots +x_n^2}{x_1+ \dots +x_n} \ d \mathrm{m}(\mathbf{x})=2/3$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623433/asymptotic-behaviour-of-a-multiple-integral-on-the-unit-hypercube

Comment: Going to look that over now. Thanks a million :)

Comment: I think my solution is easiest to understand, but it uses probability theory.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Your solution does seem very concise. I wish I understood the argument in more rigor, though - the probability theory, a new field for me, seems quite interesting.